# Class or Struct for a model similar to a relational database?

Tags: ios, class, swift, struct, reference

The application in question is built as follows:

- A user selects a job
- the job can have many components
- each component can have many lineitems.

I am not clear on how this should be structured - should this be class or structs? Seeing that only one job is being processed at a time, I am fairly confident that jobs should be a class. However, when there are multiples of a certain object type, I am not exactly clear on how to form them, like the components and lineitem objects.

The application consists of ViewControllers and TableViewControllers. All the data is fetched from a server in JSON and populated into the appropriate view as needed. Here are the object types as they are currently setup:

A job object:

```
// Job Object
//
public struct Job {
    static var globalId : String?
    static var name : String?
    static var status : String?
    static var client = Client()
    static var components = Array<Component>()
    // etc..
}
```

A Component like so:

```
// JobComponent Object
//
public struct Component {
    var name:String? = ""
    var fmRecordId : String?
    var startTS:NSDate?
    var endTS:NSDate?
    var notes:String? = ""
    var items = Array<Lineitem>()
    // etc...
}
```

and finally, a lineitem:

```
// Lineitem Object
//
public struct Lineitem {

    var fmRecordId = String()
    var itemName = String()
    var itemNumber = String()
    // etc...
}
```

All of these object are built within a `public class` called "PL".

When a user selects lineitem and edits it's values, the values are not available outside the VC in which they are edited because the VC isn't referencing the lineitem that is was passed, it is simply copying it. The same happens with components.

A workaround I found was to use the the Job struct `PL.Job.self` and always modify the components and lineitems like so where `i` = a desired index in the array:

- `PL.Job.components[i]` to access a component
- `PL.Job.components[i].items[i]` to access a specific item within that component.

However, this doesn't scale very well.

The desired behavior is to be able to pass a reference to a particular instance of an object around rather than pass around the index path of those objects in the `PL.Job` object.

I am well aware there is something wrong with how this is currently structured, but could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points:

- You can only pass class instances by reference. If you want to be able to pass a reference to a particular `LineItem` or `Component` or `Job`, and you want to be able to make changes to that object that are effective everywhere, then you need to define them as classes and not structs. Instances of struct types are *always* passed by value and not be reference. And when a value type is passed, it is copied, meaning that you create an entirely new copy of the object, and mutating the copy has no effect on the original.
- Your `Job` struct only has static properties - i.e., there will only ever be one `globalId`, `name`, `status` etc. throughout your entire application. If you want to have multiple instances of `Job`, then these should not be static properties. You say that only one `Job` will be processed at a time, so maybe that was intentional. Either way, it is still often preferable to create an instance of a `Job` class that has those properties. It certainly would give you more flexibility later if you decide to make it possible to hold references to multiple jobs in memory, or to allow the user to select between different jobs, or switch between jobs, etc. For example, you may want to allow a user to switch to the `Job` they were processing earlier without necessarily destroying the `Job` that they are working on now.

But I think the main point is that you will need to define your objects as classes if you want to be able to pass them by reference. If you modify an object that is passed by reference, all other references to the same object will show the same changes (because, after all, they are just references to the same object). That doesn't work with value types, like structs.

Comment: Very helpful in clarifying this, thank you. Is there a way to go back "up" the ladder? For instances, given an item, is it possible to get information about the job which it is associated with?

Comment: Yes, but you need to create a property that holds a reference to the job. So give `LineItem` a property called `job`, and pass a reference to the `Job` when you initialize it: `init(job: Job) { self.job = job }`